# SQL query to Insert on Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `A` with column say `id` and attributes in this `id`: `1 to 20 or any others`. I want a SQL query in such a way that `Query` will search for the particular `id` into the column say 11 then perform some action otherwise insert a new row with that (11) value.

In short

```
Search 11 in id if found then update 11 to 12 otherwise insert 11 into id
```

Comment: @R.S check what I am trying

Comment: See [Frequently Asked Questions](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/insert.php) regarding `SQL:INSERT Statement`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `If...Else`.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME WHERE id=11)
 BEGIN
     UPDATE TABLE_NAME SET ..set column with values
 END
ELSE
 BEGIN
      INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES (values....);
 END
```

Answer (score 2):

```
if not exists(select id from some table Where id = @someid)
begin
  insert sometable(id) Values (@id)
end
else
begin
 /* do something else */
end
```

Keep it simple...

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure if there is a Query for your request, But I think you can do it separately by conditional orders using php , asp etc. PHP example is here :

```
<?php
$number = 11 ;
$query = mysql_query("select * from `table` where `id` = '".$number."'");
if ( mysql_num_rows($query) >= 1 )
   {
   echo 'Existed !';
   }
else
   {
   echo 'Not existed , making :';
   $query = mysql_query('insert into `table` values ( "11", ... )');
   }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
if not exists(select top 1 id from some table Where id = @someid)
begin
  insert sometable(id) Values (@id)
end
else
begin
 -- do something
end
```